# why dynamically allocated variables will not change(when we use their addresses) like static variables

Tags: c, dynamic, linked-list, static, static-variables

head is a pointer to memory which is equal to current

```
void display(node_t **head) {  
    struct node *current = (*head);
    if((*head) == NULL) {  
        printf("List is empty \n");  
        return;  
    }  
    
while(current != NULL) {  
   printf("current->n=%d\n", current->next);  //0 1 2
   printf("head->n=%d\n", head->next);        // 0 0 0 if we assign current to its next 
   current = current->next;                // should it affect to the head because we are
                                           //because we are assigning memory address to another 
}  
}
```

sample code using static vars:

```
int *head,*current,c=1;
head=&c;
current=&c;
(*current)++;
```

head and current will change in this case

Comment: Please post both versions of your code as [mcve] and show the expected vs. the actual output for both cases

Comment: `head->n` is invalid because `node_t*` won't have members.

Comment: `current = current->next;` will NOT affect `head` because `current` and `head` are different variables.

Comment: Your second code (if you fix it so it compiles) also does not change `head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> while(current != NULL) {  
>    printf("current->n=%d\n", current->n);  //0 1 2
>    printf("head->n=%d\n", head->n);        // 0 0 0 if we assign current to its next 
>    current = current->next;                // should it affect to the head because we are
>                                            //because we are assigning memory address to another 
> }
> ```

Ignoring the inconsistent naming (is it `n` or `next`?), `head` and `current` are separate objects - nothing you do to `current` will affect `head`.

It might help if we draw a picture.  Let's assume you have a list with three nodes (I don't know what your node structure looks like, so this is pretty generic):

```
+---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
|   |   |----->|   |   |------>|   |   |---|||
+---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
```

You have a pointer to the first element (we'll call it `h`):

```
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
   h: |   |----->|   |   |----->|   |   |------>|   |   |---|||
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
```

Your `head` argument in the `display` function points to `h`:

```
      +---+
head: |   |
      +---+
        |
        V
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
   h: |   |----->|   |   |----->|   |   |------>|   |   |---|||
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
```

You initialize `current` with the value of `*head`, which is the value of `h`, so `current` points to the first node of the list:

```
      +---+
head: |   |
      +---+
        |
        V
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
   h: |   |----->|   |   |----->|   |   |------>|   |   |---|||
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
                   ^
                   |
                 +---+
        current: |   |
                 +---+
```

Each time you execute

```
current = current->next
```

that will set `current` to point to the next element in the list:

```
      +---+
head: |   |
      +---+
        |
        V
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
   h: |   |----->|   |   |----->|   |   |------>|   |   |---|||
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
                                  ^
                                  |
                                +---+
                       current: |   |
                                +---+

      +---+
head: |   |
      +---+
        |
        V
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
   h: |   |----->|   |   |----->|   |   |------>|   |   |---|||
      +---+      +---+---+      +---+---+       +---+---+
                                                  ^
                                                  |
                                                +---+
                                       current: |   |
                                                +---+
```

Nothing you do to `current` affects `head` - they are separate objects.

> ```
> int *head,*current,c=1;
> head=&c;
> current=&c;
> while(True):
>     current++;
> ```
>
> In this case, head and current will change.

Yes, because you are explicitly assigning a new value to both `head` and `current` - however, `current++` will have no effect on `head`.

And this isn't valid C, by the way - looks like you started in C and finished in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Because at this point here: `struct node *current = (*head);` you dereference head. If head is an array of node pointers, now current points to the first item of that array.

Also I would advise checking for `NULL` before dereferencing head as otherwise you have a SEGFAULT waiting to happen.